# Can I use import {address [ ] } from 'filename' to pass a address array to another smart contract's function?

Tags: solidity

In my `PersonalInfo.sol` file I want to pass address array `Users`(maybe by function `SendUserArray`, but I don't know how...) to another contract `System.sol` file. Is it possible to use `import {Users} from PersonalInfo` in `System.sol` to access the `Users` address array?

This is my PersonalInfo.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract PersonalInfo{
    address public userAddress;
    address public manager;
    address[] public Users;  // include Recruiters and Workers  


    modifier restricted (){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function PersonalInfo () public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function AddUsers()public payable{
        if(msg.sender != manager)
            Users.push(msg.sender);
    }
    function SendUsersArray()public{

    }



}
```

Comment: "Pass to another contract" - what does that even mean? Did you perhaps mean "pass to another contract's function"? In this case....... just pass it to that other contract's function when you call it.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes! I mean to pass the address array to another smart contract's function to access it.

Comment: Well... what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I just want to check if it is technically possible... and see if there is any other better option of doing so?

Comment: Yes, it is technically possible (though you'll only be able to access that array for reading of course).

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

1. Call function in `System` contract, which will call `PersonalInfo`'s `Users` function (automatically generated getter function, as `Users` array is `public`) and get the addresses (the function will have `uint256` argument - address index in the array).
2. Create a function that returns the whole array and again, call it from `System` contract.
3. Call `System`'s function that has an address array as an argument and pass `Users` array there.

Anyway, be careful, reading the whole array may be too expensive and (starting from some moment) will not fit in the block.